# ios Unable to install dependency using Pods

Tags: ios, git, cocoa, cocoapods

I am trying to install AFNetworking using Pods. I've created a pod file and when I run `pod install` I get :

> Unable to add a source with url
>   `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master-1`. You can try
>   adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.

I tried cloning into `~/.cocoapods/repos`but it gives an error: `fatal: destination path '.' already exists and is not an empty directory.`

My PodFile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show your podfile.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line:
 `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'`

**Updated:**

Run `pod init` manually when you have an internet connection.

Go to *~/.cocoapods/repos* and run `git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master`

If the problem still persist, refer this
[issue.](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4293)

Comment: Aftet this I am getting: Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master-1`.

Comment: Are you sure you have removed this line?

Comment: Yes I've deleted the line.

Comment: It says Existing Podfile found in directory after pod init

Comment: Uninstall and re-install the Cocoapods.

Comment: Would it affect my other projects? I dont wanna lose any of my work.

Comment: Take a good backup of your project. Now delete your podfile, run pod init & copy the content of your deleted podfile in new podfile.

Comment: And then run Pod install? Same error after pod install

Answer (score 0):

Please update ios version

```
platform :ios, '7.1'
```

Please use updated AFNetworking 3.0
and add

```
 platform :ios, '8.0'
```

Comment: No change in output: Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master-1`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.

Comment: please execute the following command and then try

pod repo remove master and

pod install

Answer (score 0):

Just remove master repo:

```
rm -fR ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
```

After that, run:

```
pod setup
```